# Adding and modifying multiple images to three.js canvas

Tags: three.js

I want to be able to effect images that I add to a canvas using three.js

I have this code which allows me to add the image, but then i cannot access its mesh:

```
const img_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
const pic1 = img_loader.load('pic.jpg', (texture) => {
    texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
    });
    const pic_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3), material)
    // pic_mesh.rotation.x =-0.2
    scene.add(pic_mesh)
});
```

I tried the following, but something gets lost [the image date].

```
const pic1_geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3)
const pic1_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('pic1.jpg')
pic1_texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
const pic1_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: pic1_texture } )
const pic1_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(pic1_geo, pic1_mat)
scene.add(pic1_mesh)
```

I bet there is a pricipal thing I'm missing but the docs really aren't so helpful on [threejs.org](https://threejs.org/manual/)

Comment: Because loading is asynchronous I have to ask, do you render right after this and do you render after the load? Because if you render immediately the texture won't be there yet, so you need to render later. You could also make the mesh outside of the load, and then replace the material. You could also try to use `texture.needsUpdate = true` after the texture loads? Textures don't do that automatically I think. Also, apart from the manual, you should check out the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=text#api/en/textures/Texture) for ThreeJS. They are very detailed and insightful.

Comment: There is no need to set the `needsUpdate` flag to `true` in this case. `TextureLoader` already takes care of this.